# Conjecture on a graded ring

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, combinatorics

Consider $B^{(n)}=\mathbb{F}_2[X_1,\dots,X_n]/(X_1^2,\dots,X_n^2)=\bigoplus_{i=0}^nB_i^{(n)}$, where $B_i^{(n)}$ is the space of homogeneous elements of degree $i$. Notice that $\dim_{\mathbb{F}_2}B_i^{(n)}=\binom{n}{i}$.

**Conjecture** Let $d,n$ be two positive integers such that $d\geq 2$, $n<3d$, and $n-d=2s+1$. Then there exists $\lambda \in B_d^{(n)}$ (homogeneous element of degree $d$), such that the below map 
$$B_{s+1}^{(n)}\xrightarrow{\lambda} B_{s+1+d}^{(n)}$$ (multiplication by $\lambda$) is surjective.

Comment: A more specific title will help draw attention.  I realize the title cannot state your problem fully, but it doesn't have to.  Please edit to give an idea about the topic.

Comment: Your conditions on $n,d$ seem mildly specific. Can you motivate this? Perhaps you already did some previous work that led to this?